# How to use a proxy in Haskell? (probably using a higher-rank types extension)

Tags: haskell, proxy, ghc

For the last few months, I've been putting some serious effort into learning Haskell - previously, I was a seemingly perpetual newbie with a very limited knowledge of the basics. While trying to put my new knowledge into practice on few-steps-up-from-hello-world projects, I keep finding that I want to use proxy-like patterns based on type classes. The first couple of times, when I figured out why it wasn't working, I dismissed it as "OK - I may not find a single idiomatic Haskell replacement, but odds are the problem here is that I'm using the wrong approach for the language". But what I've found is that I really *really* don't like not being able to do proxy-like things.

Trying to get a deeper understanding of why I couldn't use a proxy, after lots of experimenting, I finally figured out that with GHCs higher rank types extension, perhaps I can have proxies. But I still can't quite make it work, and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code for the best I've managed...

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Test where

--  Simple type class based on parser combinators.
class Gen g where
  get :: g x -> [(x, g x)]

instance Gen [] where
  get [] = []
  get (x:xs) = [(x, xs)]

--  Proxy type - holds a pair containing...
--    - a value of some type that supports Gen
--    - a function to indicate when an item should be skipped
newtype PROXY nestedgen x = Proxy (nestedgen x, x -> Bool)

proxyskip :: Gen nestedgen => PROXY nestedgen r -> Bool
proxyskip (Proxy (g, predf)) = case get g of
                                 []        -> False
                                 ((r,_):_) -> predf r

proxyget :: Gen nestedgen => PROXY nestedgen r -> [(r, PROXY nestedgen r)]
proxyget pr@(Proxy (sg, predf)) = if proxyskip pr
                                    then [(r2, g2) | (_, g1) <- get sg, (r2,g2) <- proxyget (Proxy (g1, predf))]
                                    else [(r3, Proxy (g3, predf)) | (r3,g3) <- get sg]

--  Instance of Gen for PROXY - get skips items where appropriate
instance Gen nestedgen => Gen (PROXY nestedgen) where
  get = proxyget

--  Test "parser"
--  Get the specified number of items, providing them as a list (within
--  the list of nondeterministic (result, state) pairs).
getN :: Gen g => Int -> g x -> [([x], g x)]
getN n g | (n < 0)  = error "negative n"
         | (n == 0) = [([], g)]
         | True     = [(r1:r2, g2) | (r1, g1) <- get g, (r2, g2) <- getN (n-1) g1]

--  Wrap some arbitrary "parser" in a PROXY that skips over the letter 'l'
proxyNotL :: Gen gb => gb Char -> PROXY gb Char
proxyNotL gg = (Proxy (gg, \ch -> (ch /= 'l')))

call_f0 :: Gen gb => (Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)]) -> gb Char -> [(r, PROXY gb Char)]
call_f0 f0 g0 = f0 (proxyNotL g0)

test :: Gen gb => (Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)]) -> gb Char -> [(r, gb Char)]
test f0 g0 = [(r, g2) | (r, Proxy (g2, _)) <- call_f0 f0 g0]
```

The last remaining error occurs on the line `call_f0 f0 g0 = f0 (proxyNotL g0)`...

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( Test.hs, Test.o )

Test.hs:44:21:
    Could not deduce (ga ~ PROXY gb)
    from the context (Gen gb)
      bound by the type signature for
                 call_f0 :: Gen gb =>
                            (Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)])
                            -> gb Char
                            -> [(r, PROXY gb Char)]
      at Test.hs:44:1-33
      `ga' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             call_f0 :: Gen gb =>
                        (Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)])
                        -> gb Char
                        -> [(r, PROXY gb Char)]
           at Test.hs:44:1
    Expected type: ga Char
      Actual type: PROXY gb Char
    In the return type of a call of `proxyNotL'
    In the first argument of `f0', namely `(proxyNotL g0)'
    In the expression: f0 (proxyNotL g0)
```

Looking at the problematic function...

```
call_f0 :: Gen gb => (Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)]) -> gb Char -> [(r, PROXY gb Char)]
call_f0 f0 g0 = f0 (proxyNotL g0)
```

The `f0` function is (if I understand higher rank types correctly) a polymorphic function passed as a parameter, with type `Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)]`. In translating-to-C terms, the caller has passed in a function pointer, but has not supplied the vtable pointer.

The `proxyNotL` function returns something of type `PROXY gb Char`, and there's an instance declaration `instance Gen nestedgen => Gen (PROXY nestedgen) where ...`, so that `PROXY gb Char` instances `Gen` provided `gb` instances `Gen`, which it does according to the type signature for `call_f0`.

Basically, as far as I can tell, GHC should say "can I provide the vtable that `f0` requires... hmmm... yes, since `PROXY gb` instances `Gen`, and I know about `PROXY` and `gb`, yes I can".

So... why is GHC refusing to unify `ga` and `Proxy gb`? Why is GHC refusing to call a polymorphic function, with an argument value that should be supported by the polymorphic type of that function?

Or alternatively, what am I completely misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to explicitly specify that the function `f0` must be polymorphic by adding the universal quantifier `forall ga.` to your type signatures:

```
call_f0 :: Gen gb => (forall ga. Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)]) -> gb Char -> [(r, PROXY gb Char)]
test :: Gen gb => (forall ga. Gen ga => ga Char -> [(r, ga Char)]) -> gb Char -> [(r, gb Char)]
```

Otherwise, GHC will put an implicit `forall ga.` at the outermost level, meaning that the caller would get to decide which `ga` should be used, while GHC has correctly deduced that these functions must be able to choose themselves that `ga` should be `PROXY gb`.

In other words, when using `RankNTypes` to require a polymorphic argument, you must always use an explicit quantifier to specify this.

Comment: Tested and it compiles, but :loading it into gchi, I'm not getting the result I was hoping for. Probably just some silly bug somewhere, though - I'm sure I can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Bug solved - silly mistake as expected - in `proxyget`, I had the `then` and `else` the wrong way around. Now, I'm getting exactly the results I wanted. Thanks again for the help - and especially for that insight about putting `forall` in a different place giving a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "proxy" in this context.  But I gather you *may* mean a data type representing instances of `Gen`.

Taking the `Gen` typeclass

```
class Gen g where
    get :: g x -> [(x, g x)]
```

the type `forall g. Gen g => g x` should be representable by a concrete data type (constructor).  If you have such a value, say `a`, the *only* valid operation is to apply `get`, giving us:

```
a :: forall g. Gen g => g x
get a :: forall g. [(x, g x)]
```

So we see that the information contained in `g x` is the same as the information contained in `[(x, g x)]`; if we want a type that can represent any such `g`, we take the greatest fixed point:

```
newtype G x = G { unG :: [(x, G x)] }
```

`G` should now be able to represent any `Gen`

```
toG :: Gen g => g x -> G x
toG = G . map (second toG) . get
```

and it is itself an instance of `Gen`

```
instance Gen G where
    get (G as) = as
```

Is that anything like what you wanted?

Comment: This is one of those things I'll need to stare at and think about while properly awake. I like that it doesn't appear to need extensions, but I'm not sure it does what I need. Defining some arbitrary type that instances Gen isn't the point - I already defined an instance for []. The point is that one type must act as a proxy for another - wrapping a value of the other type, and translating wrapping calls to the wrapped values `get` within the wrappers `get`.

Comment: In a practical example, the proxy might keep a count of how many wrapped-value `get` calls were made to support a longest-match choice. What composed parser is used for each choice doesn't matter, so long as all of these are based on the single primitive `get` parser. This is basically the object-oriented proxy design pattern - though the proxy pattern is actually much older than OOP, and was e.g. often done in C using function pointers and type-punning for "polymorphism" before C++ or OOP were well known.

Comment: Your `toG` seems to do some wrapping, but I don't see an obvious way to add the extra layer of functionality (e.g. counting gets - or, in the test thing in the question, skipping over certain items) that's the whole point of using a proxy. But maybe I'm just not thinking straight ATM.